# xstring testing: help needed for testing chords typeset with leadsheets package

Tags: strings, xstring, music, leadsheets

For a personal songbook project I use the leadsheets package. Later on, I want to automatically typeset guitar chord diagrams based on the chords of a song, even if the song is transposed via the leadsheets options.
For now, I am not even able to run a basic MWE checking for the chord that will be printed.

I tried using xstring's \IfEqCase without luck:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{xstring}

\setchords{
  sharp = \#,
  flat = b,
}

\newcommand{\myiftest}[1]{%
  \textbf{Argument:} #1 \\%
  \textbf{IfEqCase:} %
  \IfEqCase{#1}{%
  {C}{C Major}%
  {Db}{Db Major}%
  }[Unknown chord: #1]%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{song}[transpose=1]{key=C} % chords are transposed up one semitone, C becomes Db
    \textbf{Chord:} \writechord{C} \\
    \myiftest{\writechord{C}}
  \end{song}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

I expect the output to be "Db Major". What do I have to do to make \IfEqCase recognize the argument correctly as the string "Db"? Or is there a different way of achieving the desired result?

Please excuse my english, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Sorry, but this cannot work, because `\writechord` doesn't work by full expansion. What's your real aim?

Comment: There are two ways I have been able to get things to work for me when I have these kinds of issues. BUT, I _am_ sure there are some issues with this approach (otherwise @egreg would have suggested this). One is to compare to `\writechord{<arg>}` instead of `<arg>`: `\IfEqCase{#1}{{\writechord{C}}{C Major}{\writechord{Db}}{Db Major}}[Unknown chord: #1]%`. This approach sometimes requires to be done with a group as it may also need a `\noexpandarg` (does not seems to be needed in this particular case).

Comment: The second approach is to use `\detokenize{\writechord{<seg>}}`:     `\IfEqCase{\detokenize{#1}}{{\detokenize{\writechord{C}}}{C Major}{\detokenize{\writechord{Db}}}{Db Major}}[Unknown chord: #1]%`

Comment: @PeterGrill `\writechord` is the command, that actually transposes the given chord by x semitones set by the `song` option `transpose=`. I don't see how your approaches could work, as the chord is not actually transposed when using '\detokenize`. Maybe I just don't understand correctly.

Comment: @egreg the leadsheets package actually has a command `\expandcode`. The documentation says, that it fully expands code it is given as an argument. So I tried calling `\myiftest{\expandcode{\writechord{C}}}`, but this does not make any difference in the result. My aim is to print chord diagrams using the package guitarchordschemes, but it has to work when a song is transposed. Say a song has a C chord, I want it to automatically print the chord scheme for C, but if I transpose the song by one semitone C becomes Db (or C#), so the scheme for C# or Db has to be printed.

Comment: @KSTNR `\expandcode` can do nothing, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I don't fully understand expansion. Is there really no way to fully expand `\writechord{C}` to recieve the string `Db` in this example?

Comment: @KSTNR: Sorry, don't understand the music related issue you mention. Perhaps you should update your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  that you suspect will not work with the `detokenize{}` method. The `\IfStrEqCase` is only to determine which case you are dealing with.